# Convert SQL query for a different database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

Is there a tool to convert from one SQL query of one database to another?

For SQLite

```
CREATE TABLE ConstantValues(
    Id int AUTOINCREMENT primary key,
    VariableName varchar(50),
    Values varchar(150)
)
```

For SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE ConstantValues(
    Id INTEGER identity(1,1) primary key,
    VariableName varchar(50),
    Values varchar(150)
)
```

Similarly it is different for Oracle and SQL Server. Also in the foreign key constraints declaration, if there is a tool so that we can get SQL from any database to any database, it would be really helpful for me.

I have created a function like this, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution:

```
private string changeSQL(string sql)
{
    switch (dbtype)
    {
        case dbType.SQLite:
            sql = sql.Replace(" int ", " INTEGER ");
            sql = sql.Replace(" identity(1,1) ", " AUTOINCREMENT ");
            break;
        case dbType.MsAscess:
            sql = sql.Replace(" int ", " ");
            sql = sql.Replace(" identity(1,1) ", "");
            sql = sql.Replace("AUTOINCREMENT", "AUTOINCREMENT");

            break;
    }
    return (sql);
}
```

Similarly for SQLite, concatenation is done using `||` while in SQL Server it is done using `+`.

Comment: Just reviewed a 3rd party app that was ported like this from Oracle to MSSQL. They wrote code to implement SEQUENCES. Except in simple cases, switching RDBMS should involve a redesign of the database as well.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 6):

[SwisSQL Console 5.0](http://www.swissql.com/products/sql-translator/sql-converter.html)

Console offers an instant solution providing quick and reliable SQL query conversion utility that accelerates migration. Console supports migration across Oracle, SQL Server, IBM DB2, MySQL, Sybase, PostgreSQL, Informix and Netezza databases. This software also has features to test the converted SQLs in target databases.

Comment: I think its the only tool ! but why is it , such tools should have been developed by many people ,I am thinking to develop one too!

Comment: @Thunder: SQL is a fiendishly complex language and each vendor has a different dialect.  Translating from one dialect to another is very difficult to get 100% right.  That's why there aren't many tools that do this.  There aren't even many tools that work really well with multiple databases.

Comment: That link no longer works. The TLD shows the same content as https://www.manageengine.com. There seems to have been a series of acquisitions in this area. Is there still a derived product that does the same thing as SwisSQL used to do?

Answer (score 5):

first you need to know and understand that every SQL engine works with a different SQL grammar. Despite the SQL ANSI standard, no language on earth respects it 100%. Moreover, every large and known SQL engine adds own methods and stuff to the original grammar.

So, if you want to do a conversion, the easiest way is to achieve a middle SQL layer. That means, to create an agnostic SQL grammar out of the very common features in every well known SQL engine (it would result in something like SQL ansi plus every feature present in every engine, like TOP). Once you have this, you have to make the conversion to this middle layer, and from this middle layer for each SQL variation you need.

I told you this because I needed this exact thing at my work, and that was the only way to actually achieve it, and made it reusable. Having a tool gives you the job to actually manually convert every single query, and make huge SWITCHs just to choose the query, or to have an inherited class for every engine.

I tell you what I've done: I created the BNF of my SQL middle grammar, then created a tree parser with GoldParser for C#. Then I created individual rules for each rule in the grammar to be converted to each SQL dialect. It's a huge and tedious job, I know. But they'd paid me to do it...

If you don't have the time to accomplish this, you could use ODBC. Every SQL engine has an ODBC connector, and the ODBC itself will act as a middle abstract layer. But, it's not as happy as it sounds, because only simple queries will maintain this illusion... hard stuff like UNION, JOINs, and metadata creation won't be the same.

I hope it helped,

good luck

Comment: I happened to meet the same situation to convert sql query for MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, ACCESS for our software product. Could you make your code open source? I think it will be helpful for beginners. Thanks your work.

Comment: @Alejandro Is there any open source code that is similar to your approach? Really would need this too, because for the different conversions of Oracle SQL, MSSQL etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to support multiple database management systems, I'd do it thoroughly, with a Data Access Layer for each system. It'd require some amount of work, of course, but the modularity would be quite beneficial.

One alternative I'm quite happy with, is DevExpress' XPO. It's an Object Relational Mapping system that supports multiple databases. You design your classes, define a proper connection string, and the database schema will be created for you, and you can apply crud to your classes easily in code. In order to use a different database system, only change the connection string!

And no, I'm not affiliated with DevExpress other than as a very pleased customer.

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/info.xml

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an automated tool, but the best resource I've found for understanding the differences between the different SQL implementations is O'Reilley's SQL Cookbook by Anthony Molinaro. 
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009762/

He shows how to solve many different problems with clever SQL queries, including presenting side by side solutions for Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, MySQL and Postgres when they use different syntax or proprietary features. Changing your code to work with a different database is alot easier given descriptions of how they systems differ.

Molinaro also does a nice job of explaining windowing queries (or what Oracle calls analytic queries) which are well worth the time to learn, as you can accomplish things very efficiently with a query that previously required custom client code that wasted bandwidth and time.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ has a SQL parser and can generate a SQL expression tree for a variety of target dialects. You can use [jOOQ as a Java SQL parser library](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/), [command line tool](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-cli/), or directly on the website for free: https://www.jooq.org/translate

Your input query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ConstantValues(
    Id int AUTOINCREMENT primary key,
    VariableName varchar(50),
    Values varchar(150)
)
```

Produces the following output query for SQL Server:

```sql
create table CONSTANTVALUES (
  Id int identity(1, 1) not null,
  VariableName varchar(50),
  Values varchar(150),
  primary key (Id)
)
```

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Answer (score -1):

give me details about query converter for diff databases

thats your artical " Convert SQL query for a different database "